# Brew Installing Wrong Wheels On Mac

Tags: python, homebrew, pip

When I install numpy with pip I see it installing `numpy-1.21.0-cp39-cp39-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl` however I'm not using macosx_10_9 -- I'm using Mac OS 11.4.

Why isn't it installing instead `numpy-1.21.0-cp39-cp39-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl` which I see listed at https://pypi.org/project/numpy/#files?

I upgraded my Mac to 11.4 this morning (and I guess it was 10.9 before the upgrade but not totally sure). I use homebrew for python. Here is exactly what I'm doing:

```
Johns-Mac-mini:build_mac_numpy jdimatteo$ sw_vers
ProductName:    macOS
ProductVersion: 11.4
BuildVersion:   20F71
Johns-Mac-mini:build_mac_numpy jdimatteo$ which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
Johns-Mac-mini:build_mac_numpy jdimatteo$ python3 --version
Python 3.9.5
Johns-Mac-mini:build_mac_numpy jdimatteo$ brew list | grep python
python@3.9
Johns-Mac-mini:build_mac_numpy jdimatteo$ python3 -m venv venv2
Johns-Mac-mini:build_mac_numpy jdimatteo$ source venv2/bin/activate
(venv2) Johns-Mac-mini:build_mac_numpy jdimatteo$ pip install numpy==1.21.0 scipy==1.7.0
Collecting numpy==1.21.0
  Downloading numpy-1.21.0-cp39-cp39-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (16.9 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 16.9 MB 45.0 MB/s 
Collecting scipy==1.7.0
  Downloading scipy-1.7.0-cp39-cp39-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (32.1 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 32.1 MB 18.8 MB/s 
Installing collected packages: numpy, scipy
Successfully installed numpy-1.21.0 scipy-1.7.0
(venv2) Johns-Mac-mini:build_mac_numpy jdimatteo$
```

As far as I can tell, the numpy install works correctly. What is the difference between `numpy-1.21.0-cp39-cp39-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl` and `numpy-1.21.0-cp39-cp39-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl`? I would expect it to not work at all when it doesn't match the Mac OS version.

Comment: Please don’t add additional information as a comment. Just edit your post to show that new information. I went ahead and did that but still… Just always edit your post to add more info.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the difference between `numpy-1.21.0-cp39-cp39-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl` and `numpy-1.21.0-cp39-cp39-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl`?

The first appears to be for [x86-64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64) processors and the second for [ARM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture) processors.

> As far as I can tell, the numpy install works correctly.

Going out on a limb, I am guessing your Mac mini doesn't have an ARM processor and is probably using an Intel one.

> I would expect it to not work at all when it doesn't match the Mac OS version.

OS version seems somewhat irrelevant in this case, and (guessing again) is probably just a guide as to the minimum OS supported. The instruction set the `.whl` files were designed for is far more relevant (i.e. as a rule, programs for ARM processors will not run on x86 processors and vice versa).

Regarding the Mac OS 11 label specifically, [Apple has been transitioning its hardware from Intel to Arm processors for the last couple years](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_transition_to_Apple_silicon). So Mac OS 11 is probably the most current version of Mac OS for those devices (ex. the [Mac Mini M1](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP823)).